# Have there been any experiments in which the Earth's electromagnetic field was used to do work?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, estimation, geomagnetism

Simply speaking using faraday's law to generate electricity with the use of earth's magnetic field.

I'm not talking about some revolutionary new way of generating electricity that would end our energy needs. But some sort of experiment that does it even if the emf produced is very weak and the emf was used to power a tiny LED or something.

If I took a bunch of loops of copper wire and spun it incredibly fast, would I be able to produce even nanovolts?

Comment: The Earth’s magnetic field does work every time it turns a compass needle, so we’ve been doing this since the dawn of civilization.

Comment: @knzhou I meant generating current with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly generate a measurable emf this way, but it is not practical for generating power, considering you need power to spin the coil.

If you spin a coil of area $A$ and $N$ turns at a frequency of $f$ such that the normal component of the magnetic field through it oscillates between $\pm B$ (Earth's magnetic field), the root mean square (RMS) voltage you generate is
$$V = \sqrt 2\pi fBNA=\sqrt 2\pi\approx(2.22\times10^{-4}\ \text{ V/m}^2\text{/Hz/turn})\ fNA,$$

assuming $B \approx 50\ \mu\text T$. This means that a single loop that is a modest $10\text{ cm}^2$ in area, spun slowly at $1 \text{ Hz}$, can generate $222\text{ nV}$ RMS.